# jQuery UI: Draggable to nested sortable does not remove styles from

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

In this Fiddle (jsfiddle.net/s6s4R/12/) I have some Draggables and a Sortable within a Sortable
The draggables are connected with sortable (.region)

Sorting between sortables seems to work fine, but when I drag a draggable into one of the sortables the temporary styles decorated by Draggable are not removed when sortable is reciving the draggable causing the dropped draggable to be absolute positioned among things.

Is this the default behaviour, bug or some misconfiguration?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Comment: It works when I use a custom helper, http://jsfiddle.net/s6s4R/13/